Query nested json columns in postgresql
I want to return Germany and UK from the below json column/string.
{
 "id": 1,
  "name": "phone",
  "components": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "type": "screen",
      "manufacturers": [
       {
         "id": 1,
          "name": "a",
          "country": "Germany"
        }
      ]
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
      "type": "keyboard",
      "manufacturers": [
        {
         "id": 1,
          "name": "a",
          "country": "UK"
        }
     ]
   }
  ]
}


Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

TL;DR:
select 
  json_array_elements(
    json_array_elements(
      json->'components'
    )->'manufacturers'
  )->>'country' as component_manufacturer_country
from foo

fiddle
See 9.16. JSON Functions and Operators.
From the inmost part of the expression to the outer:

-> indexes to the components attributes as json
because components is an array, we split to rows using json_array_elements()
repeat steps 1 & 2 with the manufacturers attribute
->> indexes to the country attribute as text


Using a JSONPATH query, that should be simple:
SELECT * FROM jsonb_path_query('your JSON string', 'strict $.**.country');

 jsonb_path_query 
══════════════════
 "Germany"
 "UK"
(2 rows)

